# Oracle SQL how to remove duplicates formed as a result of multiple left joins while joining three or more tables?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Below is my table structure, there are three tables a,b and x

```
                Table a                                                       Table b 

STEP_ID   FORMAT  START_POSITION  FIELD_LENGTH  FUID                        FUID     FNAME
  1         null        4                 9        6                          6      A No
  1         null       14                10        7                          7      B No
  1         null       24                10        8                          8      C No
  1         null       36                 8        9                          9      D No


           Table x

     RID   IND    FLAG   CHAR  

      1     N       Y     3
      1     N       Y     1
      1     N       Y     0
      1     Y       N     2
```

The below is what I tried,`

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.STEP_ID,
CASE
WHEN b.FNAME = 'A No' THEN 'A NO'
WHEN b.FNAME = 'B No' THEN 'B NO'
WHEN b.FNAME = 'C No' THEN 'C NO'
WHEN b.FNAME = 'D No' THEN 'D NO'
END AS F_ID,
a.FORMAT,
x.IND,
x.FLAG,
x.CHAR
(a.START_POSITION - lag(a.START_POSITION + a.FIELD_LENGTH,1,1) OVER (ORDER BY a.START_POSITION))
AS BLANK
FROM s1.a a
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT FNAME,FUID FROM s1.b) b ON b.FUID = a.FUID
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT RID,CHAR,IND,FLAG FROM s1.x) x ON x.RID = a.STEP_ID
WHERE  a.STEPID = 1;
```

My output should be in the below format, but I am getting duplicates when I use the above query

```
STEP_ID    F_ID   FORMAT   IND   FLG   CHAR   BLANK   STATUS

  1        A NO    null     N     Y      3      3       S
  1        B NO    null     N     Y      1      1       S
  1        C NO    null     N     Y      0      0       S
  1        D NO    null     Y     N      2      2       S
```

Then I need to have STATUS as S if values in CHAR and BLANK are same for all the rows, if there is mismatch need F, I've been working on this for nearly a week and trying to learn kindly help me...

Comment: Which rows from A do you want to join with which rows from X?

Comment: I actually need to join all the three tables to produce the output table? The columns are mentioned in the query that I have tried. I'm getting duplicates and need to remove them, or please help with an alternative query to produce the desired output

Comment: 's1.a' has the alias a

Comment: @henele, I think you didn't understand the concept of join correctly. Whenever you join a table with another table, it joins a row with its all matching values on another table. That's why we always try to join the tables on primary key. It matches with exactly 1 row in both table since primary key is unique. In table X you have 4 rows having id 1. So 1 from table a matches 4 times to table x and produces 4 rows instead of 1. Hence you are seeing duplicates rows in result. Please use another join condition to get a single record from table x. Same as you have done between a and b using FUID.

Answer (score 1):

When you are joining the table x table with table a, it is going to give you cross multiplied results which is 16 rows. Also you do not need to add select statement every time you are JOINing..

So to get rid of duplicates, you can try that with row_number function.

```
Select * from (Select a.STEP_ID,
CASE
WHEN b.FNAME = 'A No' THEN 'A NO'
WHEN b.FNAME = 'B No' THEN 'B NO'
WHEN b.FNAME = 'C No' THEN 'C NO'
WHEN b.FNAME = 'D No' THEN 'D NO'
END AS F_ID,
a.FORMAT,
x.IND,
x.FLAG,
x.CHAR
(a.START_POSITION - lag(a.START_POSITION + a.FIELD_LENGTH,1,1) OVER (ORDER BY 
a.START_POSITION)) blank,
row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY FNAME order by FUID) rn 
FROM s1.a a LEFT JOIN si.b b ON ON b.FUID = a.FUID
             LEFT JOIN x ON x.RID = a.STEP_ID)
 WHERE rn = 1;
```

I am also sharing a link for you to understand row_number. [ROW_NUMBER](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm)

To fulfill other two requirements: you can join your tables, One using rownum. See below:

```
Select t.STEP_ID, t.FNAME, t.FORMAT,  x.RID, x.IND, x.FLAG, x.CHARS, t.blank, CASE WHEN t.blank = x.CHARS THEN 'S' ELSE 'F' END STATUS
from  
(Select a.*, rownum as global_id,  (a.START_POSITION - lag(a.START_POSITION + a.FIELD_LENGTH,1,1) OVER (ORDER BY a.START_POSITION)) blank, b.FNAME
from taba a
LEFT JOIN tabb b ON a.FUID = b.FUID
) t JOIN
(Select RID, IND, FLAG, CHARS, rownum rid2 from (Select tabx.*, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY tabx.CHARS order by tabx.CHARS) rn2 from taba JOIN tabx ON STEP_ID = RID)  where rn2 = 1) x
ON t.STEP_ID = x.RID AND t.global_id = x.rid2;
+---------+-------+--------+-----+-----+------+-------+-------+--------+
| STEP_ID | FNAME | FORMAT | RID | IND | FLAG | CHARS | BLANK | STATUS |
+---------+-------+--------+-----+-----+------+-------+-------+--------+
| 1       | A No  | null   | 1   | N   | Y    | 0     | 3     | F      |
+---------+-------+--------+-----+-----+------+-------+-------+--------+
| 1       | B No  | null   | 1   | N   | Y    | 1     | 1     | S      |
+---------+-------+--------+-----+-----+------+-------+-------+--------+
| 1       | C No  | null   | 1   | Y   | N    | 2     | 0     | F      |
+---------+-------+--------+-----+-----+------+-------+-------+--------+
| 1       | D No  | null   | 1   | N   | Y    | 3     | 2     | F      |
+---------+-------+--------+-----+-----+------+-------+-------+--------+
```

Other way is by using your blank column which is quite simple and this way your status would 'S' and same order like your output above:

```
Select t.*, x.RID, x.IND, x.FLAG, x.CHARS, CASE WHEN t.blank = x.CHARS THEN 'S' ELSE 'F' END STATUS from (Select a.STEP_ID, b.FNAME,a.FORMAT,  (a.START_POSITION - lag(a.START_POSITION + a.FIELD_LENGTH,1,1) OVER (ORDER BY a.START_POSITION)) blank from taba a
LEFT JOIN tabb b ON a.FUID = b.FUID) t
LEFT JOIN tabx x ON t.STEP_ID = x.RID and t.BLANK = x.CHARS
+---------+-------+--------+-------+-----+-----+------+-------+--------+
| STEP_ID | FNAME | FORMAT | BLANK | RID | IND | FLAG | CHARS | STATUS |
+---------+-------+--------+-------+-----+-----+------+-------+--------+
| 1       | A No  | null   | 3     | 1   | N   | Y    | 3     | S      |
+---------+-------+--------+-------+-----+-----+------+-------+--------+
| 1       | B No  | null   | 1     | 1   | N   | Y    | 1     | S      |
+---------+-------+--------+-------+-----+-----+------+-------+--------+
| 1       | C No  | null   | 0     | 1   | N   | Y    | 0     | S      |
+---------+-------+--------+-------+-----+-----+------+-------+--------+
| 1       | D No  | null   | 2     | 1   | Y   | N    | 2     | S      |
+---------+-------+--------+-------+-----+-----+------+-------+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks @The  AG, Using the above solution I'm unable to use row_number() function over F_ID, getting an error. ORA-00904, "F_ID": Invalid Identifier

Comment: I edited the column as FNAME.. Let me know if it works?

Comment: The above code has a problem with the above output, as the CHAR column value is in different order.